# continuously listening on a pipe without closing it

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have a 32 bit winform application sending jpeg images to a 64 bit winform application. 
I use pipes for this (IPC).

Instead of closing the server pipe and reopening it i would like to keep it open and process images as they come through.

I would like to know if the following code is correct?  Also, how do I know when I have received the full byte packet?  Do I have to put a 'header' in my byte array in my client calling code with the 1st 4 bytes holding the size of the entire byte array/packet like I would with sockets?  Is there a simpler way to do this with pipes?

This is my code for the server pipe:

```
    static NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = null;
    public static void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
        pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);
        while (pipeServer != null)
        {
            if (pipeServer.IsConnected == true)
            {
                byte[] imageData = new byte[100000];
                pipeServer.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                //do stuff with data
            }
        }
    }
    static string _pipeName = "";
    public static void Listen(string PipeName)
    {
        // Set to class level var so we can re-use in the async callback method
        _pipeName = PipeName;
        // Create the new async pipe 
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName,
           PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        // Wait for a connection
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
    }
```

Comment: Important note for when you re-write this, `int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)` only reads ***up to*** `length` bytes. You need to check the result the function returns and that tells you how many bytes really got read and saved in to `buffer`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  Again, makes a lot of sense now you said it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think it is good to add header with the length/size of the array 
and maybe add a checksum or something

Comment: HI Max, yes, that was how I traditionally used with Sockets. I have never used Pipes before so I was wondering if there was another alternative. I will let this question run for a bit longer.. :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Having to do that is not something specific to Sockets. Pipes, Sockets, and even files on your hard drive are all "streams" if you want to transfer data over them you ether need a pre-defined format with separators (for example watching the stream for a `\0` or a `\r\n`) or you need header information that says how large the fields are.